# What font does Apple use for printed document?

Tags: fonts, typography, print-design, font-face, osx

Serif font such as `Times New Roman` is usually used in printing document in Windows.

What is the equivalent font in Apple?

Comment: @Marc Edwards' answer below is the perfect answer for the question in you title however the body of your question is very confusing. Microsoft does not use Times New Roman in printed documents to promote Windows. Besides that, Times New Roman *is* available on MacOS

Answer (score 2):

Helvetica Regular is the default typeface for most of Apple’s apps that can print, including Pages, TextEdit and Numbers.

Apple typically uses a mixture of Helvetica and Lucida Grande for their UI. A lot of Apple’s marketing material is set in Myriad Pro. iOS is mostly Helvetica.

Answer (score 0):

As @Const says in the comment above, Times New Roman is available on all Macs [from 10.5 on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_Roman#Uses).

However, the "old-school" Mac equivalent to Times New Roman is Times...somewhat fitting, because as [this article](http://www.typographyforlawyers.com/?page_id=1411) discusses, Times Roman and Times New Roman were Depression-era rivals:

> After Mono­type com­pleted Times New Roman, it had to license the design to then-rival Lino­type, because the Times used Linotype’s type­set­ting machines. (Think of Mono­type and Lino­type as the Depression-era Microsoft and Apple.) Since then, Mono­type has sold the font as “Times New Roman” and Lino­type has mar­keted its ver­sion as “Times Roman.”